# how to separate the channels of an RGB image in emgu?

Tags: image-processing, emgucv

I need to separate an RGB image into 3 channels. In the other words i need a code to do the following.

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> imgBgr = CvInvoke.Imread("Im.jpg").ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
Mat blue = imgBgr.BlueChannel;
Mat green = imgBgr.GreenChannel;
Mat red = imgBgr.RedChannel;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do that.

1. Use `imgBgr.Split()`. It returns an array of 3 gray images that each image represents a single color channel of the original image.
2. Use `imgBgr.Sub(color)`. It will subtract the color from the original image. For example, if you want to get red color only, remove green and blue, `imgBgr.Sub(new Rgb(0, 255, 255))` and so on.